# Run function before useState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm creating a random word generator in Next.js. I'm managing the state of the three randomly generated words with `useState`. However, React gives me an error message when I write like this:

```
const [word1, setWord1] = React.useState(generateWord());
```

Error message:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

[image]

Why is this error happening? How do I write the above code properly?

I'm assuming this issue can be mitigated by using `useEffect`, which runs in component lifecycle timings like `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. However, I only want to set the initial values upon loading the page (only `componentDidMount`). (The text fields will get new randomly generated words once the user clicks a button.)

Comment: What is "Text"? What is this `generateWord` function doing? Can you edit the post to include a more relevant and complete [mcve] as well as the error message as plain formatted and readable text?

Comment: `generateWords(): string` picks a word from a dictionary and returns it as a string. @Terry has answered this question already.

Comment: Yeah, you accepted answer just as I was leaving comment. I meant that more as a *please share the relevant code in your question so we can read what it's doing* sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mismatch happens because useState is run during SSR and so the server generates a random word but when the page is rehydrated on the client side a different random word is generated. This mismatch causes your React app to warn you about this inconsistency.

To remedy this, you can use an empty string in the useState hook, and then update the state with a randomly generated word in a useEffect hook with an empty dependency array, which only runs on the client side when your component is mounted:

```
const [word1, setWord1] = React.useState('');

// Only runs on the client
React.useEffect(() => {
  setWord1(generateWord());
}, []);
```

Comment: Mnn... now it's stuck in an infinite loop and the words keep regenerating like this: https://imgur.com/NOYGqGX

Comment: Looks like you can remedy the above behavior by making `useEffect` compare against an empty array. https://css-tricks.com/run-useeffect-only-once/
(And I just noticed that you included it in your response!)

Comment: @ric.row ...which I did. I mentioned that you need to use an empty dependency array. Your regenerating loop could be due to (1) re-rendered triggered by other parts of the app that is unintentional, or (2) you are using `word1` in your dependency array